# Is it possible to have the subcaption letters (a),(b) right next to the caption number 1? Figure 1(a): NameOfTheFigure

Tags: graphics, numbering, captions, minipage, subcaption

Within the figure environment, I have minipages that include graphics. The graphics have subcaptions because all of them belong to one figure, but I do not need a caption for figure. Instead I want the subcaption to include the figure number aswell as the subfigure letter:
"Figure 1(a): My first graphic" and "Figure 1(b): My second graphic"

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
%%----start of first figure----
\begin{minipage}[p]{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.6in]{Graphic1}
\subcaption{My first grapic} 
\label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.3cm}%
%%----start of second figure----
\begin{minipage}[p]{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.6in]{Graphic2}
\subcaption{My second graphic}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

That is the code that provides subcaptions for my graphics that look like: "(a) My first graphic", while my aim is this: "Figure 1(a): My first graphic".
I would be deeply grateful, if somebody could help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to redefine `\thesubfigure` as counter output, having `\thefigure(\alph{subfigure})`, but using `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` and `\captionsetup` is a cleaner and more flexibel way, in my point of view.

Don't forget to call `\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=...}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subfigure}{#1~\thefigure(#2)}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=subfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\centering
%%----start of first figure----
\begin{minipage}[p]{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.6in]{ente1}
\subcaption{My first grapic} 
\label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.3cm}%
%%----start of second figure----
\begin{minipage}[p]{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.6in]{ente2}
\subcaption{My second graphic}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was searching for :)